# Angular mat tree with drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-dragdrop, angular-tree-component

I am using **`angular material flat tree`** for **`drag and drop`**.

I implemented **`drag and drop`** using an example from stackblitz [**link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts).

I'm getting an error when i drag and drop parent node to child node.

> This is the error **Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined**

```
Instead of showing that error i want to disable the action of DND of parent to child.
```

This is my **[work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-flat-tree-dnd?embed=1&file=app/tree-flat-overview-example.ts&view=preview)** so far. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wans't able to reproduce the problem. can you tell me a bit more.

Comment: @JSmith , please try to drag and drop parent node to child node , then try one more time you will get an error . 

I updated my demo. Also check our  chat room. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a detailed procedure to reproduce the error

Comment: I see you have implemented my method I just saw some bugs in the display and don't have a clue if that comes from my algo or the DND process. For the moment the only problem I had was `ERROR TypeError: "siblings is undefined"`

Comment: @zerocewl When a parent is dropped into a child no error is displayed for the time being. The error is displayed on next DND action.

Comment: @JSmith , that is the problem. it's about your method. When first DND action the dragged node will slice from the data. Then another DND process i will get the error.

Comment: so you mean the display problem comes from my method?

Comment: @JSmith , no it's because the error is caused by the previous(above) code.

Comment: @AnzilkhaN The problem I saw are 1. you shouldn't be able to drag and drop a parent node to a child node 2. object 2 level 0 cannot be dragged drop to a child node of object 1 and  same for object 1 into object 2 are you ok with that?

Comment: This error getting from this code " const nodeToInsert: PARENTNODE = siblings.splice(siblingIndex, 1)[0]; " , Only when the DND process not complete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200606/discussion-between-jsmith-and-anzil-khan).

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied and pasted the `drop()` code of the example you gave and it worked.
Not sure to understand where your problem came from but still you can try delete your function and add this instead:

```
// recursive find function to find siblings of node
findNodeSiblings(arr: Array<any>, id: string): Array<any> {
  let result, subResult;
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      result = arr;
    } else if (item.children) {
      subResult = this.findNodeSiblings(item.children, id);
      if (subResult) result = subResult;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (!event.isPointerOverContainer) return;
    const visibleNodes = this.visibleNodes();
    const changedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.dataSource.data));
    const node = event.item.data;
    const siblings = this.findNodeSiblings(changedData, node.id);
    const siblingIndex = siblings.findIndex(n => n.id === node.id);
    const nodeToInsert: PARENTNODE|CHILDNODE = siblings.splice(siblingIndex, 1)[0];
    const nodeAtDest = visibleNodes[event.currentIndex];
    if (nodeAtDest.id === nodeToInsert.id) return;
    let relativeIndex = event.currentIndex; // default if no parent
    const nodeAtDestFlatNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes.find(n => nodeAtDest.id === n.id);
    const parent = this.getParentNode(nodeAtDestFlatNode);
    if (parent) {
      const parentIndex = visibleNodes.findIndex(n => n.id === parent.id) + 1;
      relativeIndex = event.currentIndex - parentIndex;
    }
    const newSiblings = this.findNodeSiblings(changedData, nodeAtDest.id);
    if (!newSiblings) return;
    newSiblings.splice(relativeIndex, 0, nodeToInsert);
    this.rebuildTreeForData(changedData);
  }
```

This doesn't really answer where your original problem came from but still I would recommend you to well understand this piece of code as it looks like it is working. and start over on a clean basis if you want to add more options.